# Split column by deliminter '+' with R

Tags: r

For example I got :

```
V1 <- c("apple + orange + banana","apple+green + orange + banana")
#careful, there is no space in "apple+green"
data <- data.frame(V1) 
                             V1
1       apple + orange + banana
2 apple+green + orange + banana
```

And I would like this kind of dataframe :

```
data_final 

              V1     V2       V3
    1       apple  orange  banana
    2 apple+green  orange  banana
```

I tried with *strsplit* :

```
strsplit(as.character(data$V1), ' +', fixed=TRUE)
```

I added a space because of the string "apple+green". 
But the result gave me a column composed by a list. 
And I want a dataframe

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completness, here is a `tidyverse` option that uses `separate` from  `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(data, col = V1, sep = " \\+ ", into = c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
#           V1     V2     V3
#1       apple orange banana
#2 apple+green orange banana
```

The `sep` argument is interpreted as a regular expression, if character, so we need to escape the `+`.

Comment: you just beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this with [splitstackshape](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/index.html) package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
x <- cSplit(data, 'V1', ' + ')
```

Result:

```
          V1_1   V1_2   V1_3
1:       apple orange banana
2: apple+green orange banana
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(data$V1), ' + ', fixed = TRUE))
#      [,1]          [,2]     [,3]    
# [1,] "apple"       "orange" "banana"
# [2,] "apple+green" "orange" "banana"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text= gsub(" \\+ ", ",", data$V1), header = FALSE)
#         V1     V2     V3
#1       apple orange banana
#2 apple+green orange banana
```